# Drupal 7: Contact Form Not Visible, Despite Permissions

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

So I've enabled the site-wide and user contact forms through the Contact module, enabled ALL of the permissions (for good measure) under the Contact permissions for ALL roles. The contact form tab appears and is accessible for all users when I'm logged into my Admin account, but doesn't appear for any other user role.

I've scoured all over Drupal forums and can only find people making the mistake of forgetting to change permissions or enable the personal user contact form. I've flushed all caches and run updates, done everything I can think of.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 4):

I was hitting a very similar issue in respect of giving Authenticated the permission `Use users' personal contact forms`, then logging in and going to `user`/`[uid]`/`contact results` in `Access Denied`.

Simply I hadn't picked up that each user has to opt in to being contacted via the Personal Contact Form.

EDIT - in a comment below @tanius has provided a link to some code that could be used to mass update the settings for 'opt in' to personal contact form.

Comment: As admin, you can mass-update the setting to opt into using the personal contact form with [this little piece of code](https://drupal.org/node/122428#comment-7017140). Use at your own risk though, and don't forget to make a backup.:-)

Comment: Thanks! You may also just take over the content so we can delete all the comments again. Much cleaner :) Tried to add this to your answer with an edit back in 2013 and only found out right now they rejected it (there are no notifications about rejected edits).

Answer (score 2):

If you trip the flood filter you will also get an access denied page. You should get a system message saying "You cannot send more than 5 messages in 1 hour. Try again later.", it prevents you from even seeing the page via the access denied text.

If this is the case, you can resolve it by going to the flood table and deleting some of the entries it. It bases it on IP address so just knock a few of those out.

Answer (score 2):

Give site wide contact contact form permission using code :-

```
<?php
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$menu)
{
  if(isset($menu['contact']))
  {
    $menu['contact']['access callback'] = TRUE;
  }
}
?>
```

*** mymodule is your custom module name.

Comment: this is a very bad idea.this will make it visible to all users even anonymous users.

Comment: at last.. this was a savior.. thank you very much :D
i want it for anonymous users..

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

1) go to admin/structure/block
2) Find the block of your contact form
3) Click Configure
4) Check visiblity settings
option - roles

Make sure none are selected so that it will be shown to all roles.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
vishal

Comment: Hi vishal - there is no block set up for the contact form so I have no visibility settings to toggle. The contact form is a page.

Comment: It does not appear as a block (not listed in my blocks area). I'm using the Contact module so I'm assuming the contact pages are dynamic and created differently for each user.

Comment: I would need access to ur dev machine for further testing. If you are int get in touch with me at my blog

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This is what I did.

Go to Structure --> Blocks

Find here "Main content" and from drop-down menu choose "Content" field. Save your settings and check.